# Fine control over the font size in Seaborn plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm currently trying to use Seaborn to create plots for my academic papers. The plots look great and easy to generate, but one problem that I'm having some trouble with is having the fine control on the font size in the plots.

My font size in my paper is 9pt and I would like to make sure the font size in my plots are either 9pt or 10pt. But in seaborn, the font size is mainly controlled through font scale `sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=0.9)`. So it's hard for me to find the right font size except through trial and error. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I also want to make sure the font size is consistent between different seaborn plots. But not all my seaborn plots have the same dimension, so it seems like using the *same font_scale* on all the plots does not necessarily create the same font size across these different plots?

I've attached my code below. I appreciate any comments on how to format the plot for a two column academic paper. My goal is to be able to control the size of the figure without distorting the font size or the plot. I use Latex to write my paper.

```
# Seaborn setting                                                                                                                                              
sns.set(style='whitegrid', rc={"grid.linewidth": 0.1})
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=0.9)                                                  
plt.figure(figsize=(3.1, 3)) # Two column paper. Each column is about 3.15 inch wide.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
color = sns.color_palette("Set2", 6)

# Create a box plot for my data                                                      
splot = sns.boxplot(data=df, palette=color, whis=np.inf,                              
        width=0.5, linewidth = 0.7)

# Labels and clean up on the plot                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
splot.set_ylabel('Normalized WS')                                                     
plt.xticks(rotation=90)                                                               
plt.tight_layout()                                                                    
splot.yaxis.grid(True, clip_on=False)                                                 
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)                                                   
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here. You can provide font sizes to the various font-related rc parameters to change the defaults, and you can pass a fontsize to any specific plotting function to specify the fonts for the elements it is creating. `font_scale` isn't the only way to do it, it's just a convenient way to change a lot of things at once.

Comment: Not answering this question, but maybe addressing a fundamental change in the approach: Take a look at the [`psfrag`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag?lang=en) package. It allows you to replace characters in a figure with strings.

Comment: @mwaskom You answered my question -- specify the font size through rc. But one thing that I think would be nice to have in seaborn is being able to specify a font_size that gets globally applied to all font properties. Because using rc, I have to individually set each font parameter (e.g., axes.labelsize, legend.fontsize).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You are right. This is a badly documented issue. But you can change the font size parameter (by opposition to font scale) directly after building the plot. Check the following example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

b = sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
b.axes.set_title("Title",fontsize=50)
b.set_xlabel("X Label",fontsize=30)
b.set_ylabel("Y Label",fontsize=20)
b.tick_params(labelsize=5)
plt.show()
```

, which results in this:

[image: Different font sizes for different labels]

To make it consistent in between plots I think you just need to make sure the DPI is the same. By the way it' also a possibility to customize a bit the [rc dictionaries](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/rcmod.py) since "font.size" parameter exists but I'm not too sure how to do that.

NOTE: And also I don't really understand why they changed the name of the font size variables for axis labels and ticks. Seems a bit un-intuitive.

Comment: What about tick size? If we set font size manually, and don't use font_scale then the axes ticks don't scale well with the figure size. As in the above figure, you can see how small are the x-ticks and y-ticks. It would be very helpful if someone tells how to increase tick size then?

Answer (score 48):

It is all but satisfying, isn't it? The easiest way I have found to specify when setting the context, e.g.:

```
sns.set_context("paper", rc={"font.size":8,"axes.titlesize":8,"axes.labelsize":5})
```

This should take care of 90% of standard plotting usage. If you want ticklabels smaller than axes labels, set the 'axes.labelsize' to the smaller (ticklabel) value and specify axis labels (or other custom elements) manually, e.g.:

```
axs.set_ylabel('mylabel',size=6)
```

you could define it as a function and load it in your scripts so you don't have to remember your standard numbers, or call it every time.

```
def set_pubfig:
    sns.set_context("paper", rc={"font.size":8,"axes.titlesize":8,"axes.labelsize":5})
```

Of course you can use [configuration files](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html), but I guess the whole idea is to have a simple, straightforward method, which is why the above works well.

Note: If you specify these numbers, specifying `font_scale` in `sns.set_context` is ignored for all specified font elements, even if you set it.

Comment: Bonus caveat for publication grade figures (not asked, so not part of the answer): You can specify `dpi` with `plt.figure`, but not with `plt.subplots`, so you have to specify it when saving `plt.savefig(filename,dpi=500)` ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028255/set-height-and-width-of-figure-created-with-plt-subplots-in-matplotlib/37405530#37405530))

Comment: This is what I use: `def defaultPlotting(): sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27),"font.size":20,"axes.titlesize":20,"axes.labelsize":20},style="white")`

Comment: Is this does not work you, check that you have no `sns.set()` statements after the `sns.set_context()` statement. Even if you don't specify any font changes in the `set()`  method, it seems to reset them at least partly.

Comment: Do these apply to the legend?

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent way too long trying to find out the actual values of the "paper" sns context. I could only find it for "talk" and honestly I am raging! Just going to use

```
sns.set_context("paper", rc{"font.size":8,"axes.titlesize":8,"axes.labelsize":5})
```

even though these might be the values anyway!!!!