# How to adjust font sizes of labels in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science

I'm trying to adjust the font size of labels in heat map in seaborn

[image]

I am using this setting

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
```

But this seems to have only adjusting the font sizes of numbers,how can I reduce font sizes of text labels

Comment: please send us the rest of your codes so that we can inspect it. thanks.

Comment: You can update the axis titles when you create them. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222162/4730972)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fine control over the font size in Seaborn plots for academic papers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220829/fine-control-over-the-font-size-in-seaborn-plots-for-academic-papers)