# Increase the font size of a Seaborn title

Tags: python-3.x, plot, seaborn

I have created a scatterplot using the following function:

```
def plot_all_seaborn(x,y,types,x_axis, y_axis, title):
    tuples = only_floats(x,y,types)
    x,y,types_new = zip(*tuples)
    frame = pd.DataFrame({x_axis:x,y_axis:y,'Model':types_new})
    sns.relplot(data=frame,
                x=x_axis, 
                y=y_axis, 
                hue="Model", 
                style="Model",
                s=500
                ).set(title=title)
```

For this plot, I want to increase the font size of the table. I have tried adding a `font_size` parameter in the `set` method, but this does not work. How can I enlarge the title?

---

Based on this link ([Fine control over the font size in Seaborn plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220829/fine-control-over-the-font-size-in-seaborn-plots)), I tried:

```
def plot_all_seaborn(x,y,types,x_axis, y_axis, title):
    tuples = only_floats(x,y,types)
    x,y,types_new = zip(*tuples)
    frame = pd.DataFrame({x_axis:x,y_axis:y,'Model':types_new})
    b = sns.relplot(data=frame,
            x=x_axis, 
            y=y_axis, 
            hue="Model", 
            style="Model",
            s=500
            )
    b.set_title("Title",fontsize=20)
    plt.show()
```

However, this returns the following error:

`AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_title'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fine control over the font size in Seaborn plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220829/fine-control-over-the-font-size-in-seaborn-plots)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I have added your suggestion to initial question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable, but you have to pass in the additional parameters as a dict.

```
def plot_all_seaborn(x,y,types,x_axis, y_axis, title):
    tuples = only_floats(x,y,types)
    x,y,types_new = zip(*tuples)
    frame = pd.DataFrame({x_axis:x,y_axis:y,'Model':types_new})
    b = sns.relplot(data=frame,x=x_axis, y=y_axis)

    b.set_title("Title", {"fontsize"=20})

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can achieve your results like so;

```
def plot_seaborn(x,y,types,x_axis, y_axis, title):
    tuples = only_floats(x,y,types)
    x,y,types_new = zip(*tuples)
    frame = pd.DataFrame({x_axis:x,y_axis:y,'Model':types_new})
    sns.relplot(data=frame,
            x=x_axis, 
            y=y_axis, 
            hue="Model", 
            style="Model",
            s=500
            ).set_title(title, fontsize=23)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no property 'fontsize'`