# Same size of Plot with different Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a little problem, i created many differents subplot. But I would like to have always the same size for the plots in Subplots. This my result and my script.

Thank you

```
    for univers in dict_contrib:
    number_plot = 2
    test = (math.ceil((len(dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'])/number_plot)))
#     fig, axs = plt.subplots((math.ceil((len(dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'])/number_plot))),number_plot,figsize=(12,8),sharex=True)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots((math.ceil((len(dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'])/number_plot))),number_plot, figsize=(11.69,6),gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[1]*test,
                                                                                                                                      'width_ratios':[1,1]},sharex=True)
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=1)
    fig.suptitle( f'Contributions - MTD {univers}',y=1,x=0)
    for ax,ptf in zip(axs,split_dict(dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'],math.ceil((len(dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'])/number_plot)))):
        itera_rows = []
        if not isinstance(ax,np.ndarray) : ax = [ax]
        for rows,ptf_selection in zip(ax,ptf):
            rows.title.set_text(dict_ptf_info[ptf_selection]['name'])
            rows.hlines(y=dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'][ptf_selection]['instrument'], xmin=0, xmax=dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'][ptf_selection]['contribution'],color=dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'][ptf_selection].colors, alpha=0.4, linewidth=8)
            for x, y, tex in zip(dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'][ptf_selection]['contribution'], dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'][ptf_selection].index, dict_contrib[univers]['MTD'][ptf_selection]['contribution']):
                t = rows.text(x, y, round(tex, 2), horizontalalignment='right' if x < 0 else 'left', 
                             verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'color':'red' if x < 0 else 'green', 'size':8})
            rows.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
            rows.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            rows.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
            rows.axvline(x=0, color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
            itera_rows.append(rows)
        rows_off = set(ax)-set(itera_rows)
        for charts in list(rows_off):
            charts.axis('off')
    fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Comment: I must to create different subplot, not just one subplot with all plot in

Comment: Could you possibly use more than one facetgrid

Comment: what's the question exactly?

Comment: I would like create 3 subplot with different plot in, but with always same size of plots.

Comment: Do you want the figure size to be reduced accordingly?  That is non trivial, but with a bit of math you could figure it out.  But there is no automatic way to do this.

Comment: Yes, because if i have a subplot with 3 plots and another subplot 1 plots. I would like to have the same size

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't particularly work that way, but the math isn't that hard for you to manually set the figure size.  Conversely you could always use the same figure size, and add fixed-sized subplots, and then trim the extra whitespace if you dont' fill all the rows.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have a little example ?

Comment: use `fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])` to manually place axes... https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes

Comment: Thank you  for your reply !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786033/add-axes-to-a-figure-with-a-fixed-size